# How to get the user details from social_django? And print all the details of all the users

Tags: django, oauth, userinfo

I want to get the detail of all the users those who have login through google oauth and want to print all the details for my project.

I am just getting the detail of the current user who have login using the google login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To list all the users signed in using `google`

```
from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth
# select_related for performance.
google_logins = UserSocialAuth.objects.select_related("user").filter(provider="google-oauth2")
for google_login in google_logins:
    print(google_login.user.pk, google_login.user.email)
```

Comment: Is this for python shell?

Comment: You can use in view as well

Comment: It worked just need to change a bit in code
instead of ```provider="google_oauth"``` used ```provider="google-oauth2"```

Comment: ofcourse print(google_login.user.pk, google_login.user.email), see updated answer